# DIV style = none, but div is still displayed (used for pop up processing graphic)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an issue with a pop up processing graphic which is inside a DIV element, and I cant make in vanish.   When needed, the graphic appears correctly, but when I try and make it display none, it is still there.

I am using the spinner function as shown here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/701197/A-master-page-level-spinner-animation

So, I have the div elements in my master page:

```
  <!--Content start-->
        <div id="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent2" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            <div class="clr"></div>
            <div id="SpinnerContainer"></div> 
            <div id="Spinner" style="background:url(/images/loader.gif) no-repeat center #fff;"></div> 
        </div>
        <!--Content end-->
```

I have some java script in my master page to make it visible as follows:

```
 function ToggleSpinnerBlock(Visible) {
        var displayValue = Visible ? "block" : "none";
        document.getElementById("SpinnerContainer").style.display = displayValue;
        document.getElementById("Spinner").style.display = displayValue;

        var isIE = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') > 0;
        if (Visible && isIE) {
            $('#Spinner').css("backgroundImage", "");
            setTimeout("AppendSpinnerImageForIE();", 10);
        }
    }
```

And a connected CSS style as follows:

```
/* Loader spinner styles */
  div#SpinnerContainer
    {
        position: absolute;    
        display: none;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        opacity:0.4;
        filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
        z-index: 1000; /* Important to set this */
    } 
 div#Spinner
    { 
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width:50px;
        height: 50px;
        top: 48%;
        left: 48%;            
        z-index:1001;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

In my sub-forms, my buttons call the javascript, as follows:

```
                    <asp:Button ID="btnFilter"  ToolTip="Select to search for patients using the above filter criteria" runat="server" Text="Filter" 
                        onclick="btnFilter_Click" OnClientClick="return BeforePostBack()" CssClass="btnDownloadSearchClear"/>
```

And thats all good - I press the button, and I get my spinner.  Great.

But, in my code, I need to be able to hide the spinner.  So in my c# server code, I use:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "HideSpinner();", true);
```

Which calls a new javascript function in my sub (main app) pages as follows:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent2" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function BeforePostBack() {
        $('#PostBackResult').text('');
        ToggleSpinnerBlock(true);
        return true; //So that allow post back to server
    }
    function HideSpinner() {
        $('#PostBackResult').text('');
        HideSpinnerBlock(false);
        return true; //So that allow post back to server
    } 


</script>
```

Which then calls the master page javascript as follows:

```
    function HideSpinnerBlock(Visible) {
        var displayValue = Visible ? "block" : "none";
        document.getElementById("Spinner").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("SpinnerContainer").style.display = 'none';

    }
```

Now I know 100% that the javascript HideSpinnerBlock is being called (I have put alerts, and bad code to trap it via Firebug), and it is being called, but the spinner bug remains on screen.

Any ideas?

PS - Yes, I know my HideSpinnerBlock can call ToggleSpinnerBlock with a False setting, but after this failed, I decided to hard code it.

Any ideas?  I am pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: instead of registerstartupscript, have you tried the onReady?

Comment: Will it work if you run document.getElementById("Spinner").style.display = 'none'; from the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try setting background to none also.   That is where your spinner is.  You should really just make a class with the properties such as ...

```
.hideSpinner {

    display: none !important;
    background: none !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Then just add the class...

```
var d = document.getElementById("Spinner");
d.className = d.className + " hideSpinner";
```